# Chrome does not get session storage on popstate

Tags: jquery

I have a function that is getting session storage when clicking the backbutton

It does not get the session storage in Chrome but the script works properly in Safari and firefox.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    const data =JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("DataSaved"));
    console.log(data);
    success(data); //function
 });
```

Comment: Did not get session storage data which is store

Comment: I rewrote your question so it makes more sense.

Comment: [Have a look to see if anyone else has this issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=popstate+sessionstorage+site:stackoverflow.com)